# How to `inject` `$window` object to the `config` in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to inject the `$window` object into the `config` method in AngularJS, but I keep getting an error...

What is the correct way to do this?

Here is my code :

```
angular.module('myApp', ['$window']) //is this wrong?

  .config(function ($window) { //this is not the way?
      console.log($window); //console.log fails //error
  })

  .controller("main", function($scope) {
    $scope.index = 0;
    $scope.num = number[$scope.index];

   $scope.increase = function () {
     $scope.index += 1;
     $scope.num = number[$scope.index];
   }
})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3JEmdYgcC18itXkZp3th?p=preview)

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Many services will not be available in the .config block. You should probably try to use .run istead.

Comment: Idk your use case to use $window in config? Are you trying to fetch location?

Answer (score 84):

you can't inject `$window` service to the config as services are not initialized at config time yet. however, you can inject them providers and get an instance. in your case:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

 .config(function ($windowProvider) {
   var $window = $windowProvider.$get();
   console.log($window);
 })
```

Answer (score 11):

Only ***constants and providers*** can be injected in **config block**. `$window` is a ***service***. & it might not be available or configured while execution of config block so angular prevents it from using it.

You can use **run block**. This acts as a main method for your angular app. This is executed just right before application is instantiated. By the time run block is executed all the service will be finished configuring and are ready to be injected. So you can use `$window` as below,

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['$window']) 

  .run(function ($window) { //use run rather than config
      console.log($window); 
  })

  .controller("main", function($scope) {
    $scope.index = 0;
    $scope.num = number[$scope.index];

   $scope.increase = function () {
     $scope.index += 1;
     $scope.num = number[$scope.index];
   }
  })
```

Comment: This will not work: angular.module('myApp', ['$window'])  because "$window" is not a module.