# Routing logic with authentification and otherwise

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been working on an authentification system for my angular application.
I managed to make some states 'secure' with a redirection to a login page with the following config code.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $stateProvider
    .state('home',
    {
        url : '/home',
        templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
        resolve : {
            authenticate: authenticate
        }
     }
}
```

`authenticate` is the function that resolves or rejects the promise.

```
function authenticate($q, $location, $timeout) {

    //simplified version
    var authed = false;

    if (authed == true) {
        return $q.when();
    }
    else {
        $timeout(function() { $location.path('/login'); })
        return $q.reject();
    }
}
```

This works beautifully for every url inside my application:

```
http:myproject.com/#/privatepage redirects to http:myproject.com/#/login
http:myproject.com/#/ redirects to http:myproject.com/#/login
```

But `http:myproject.com/` enters the `otherwise` method of $urlRouterProvider, redirects to #/home then redirects to #/login several times and I get an angular error:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

I believe this happens around the line `return $q.reject();` of the authenticate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather make a check that if a user is not logged in then point the `otherwise` state to login else to home.

Something like this...

```
if (loggedIn) {

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    } else {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    }
```

`loggedIn` can be set to be equal to a boolean value depending upon if the user is logged in.

Comment: I get an Error: $injector:modulerr if I add a condition inside .config

Comment: You forgot to inject `$urlRouterProvider` in your `.config`

Comment: no, I used it originally. However I'm using a $window... which doesn't work

Comment: Did you inject `$window`...?

Comment: I do this: .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $window) adding $window breaks the app...

Comment: Then use javascritps `window`. BTW where and why are you `window`..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961949/how-to-inject-window-object-to-the-config-in-angular I'll mark your anwer as correct since it solves my infinite redirection. Thanks