# Correct syntax to inject angular service into angular value definition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code works:

```
angular.module("appname").value("RavenConfig", {
    dsn: "key",
    config: {
        maxMessageLength: 1000,
    },
});
```

The following code does not work:

```
RavenConfig = function($window) {
    return {
        dsn: "key",
        config: {
            maxMessageLength: 1000,
        },
    }
};

RavenConfig.$inject = ["$window"];

angular.module("appname").value("RavenConfig", RavenConfig);
```

I get `Error: Raven has not been configured.`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
angular.module('appname').value('RavenConfig', RavenConfig);
function RavenConfig($window) {
    return {
        dsn: "key",
        config: {
            maxMessageLength: 1000
        }
    }
};
RavenConfig.$inject = ['$window'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Values are set up during the configuration/bootstrapping process, to be made available to services later. You will need to go through the provider. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961949/how-to-inject-window-object-to-the-config-in-angular).

Answer (score 0):

`value` is intended for constants. It is [a wrapper around `factory` service](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.6/src/auto/injector.js#L735) with dummy factory function.

Use `factory` for services that have dependencies:

```
angular.module("appname").factory("RavenConfig", RavenConfig);|
```